# Passing arguments to command line upon button click in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to pass a string of arguments that will open a command line, and pass the specified arguments upon a button click.  I am trying to define one value as the contents of a text box (constant ping to the IP address listed in the box).  It will open the command line but will not pass any arguments, can anyone assist?

```
private void Pingbutt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        String s = Cmiptxt.Text;
        proc.Arguments = (@"c/ ping" + s + "-t");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a space before and after your ip, [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) would make this easier the read

```
proc.Arguments = string.Format("c/ ping {0} -t", s);
```

Alternatively, a simple way to implement this would be to use the [Process.Start(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) overload

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", string.Format("c/ ping {0} -t", s));
```

Comment: even using the string.Format it is acting the same, opens the command prompt but it is not entering "ping" the ip or -t.  I am unfamiliar with the Process.Start(string, string) overload...

Comment: I figured it out, I neglected to remove the second process start argument and it was attempting to start 2 separate processes...

Answer (score 0):

I try this one. not working corectly. cmd open. not runing command.

```
 private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Process.Start("cmd.exe", string.Format("ipconfig"));
    }
```